# CPLEX cannot recognize scientific notation in .lp file created by C++

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex, scientific-notation

I wrote the model in C++ to generate model20.lp, and CPLEX could read the file normally.

But when the model was expanded, CPLEX could not read the file then showed "Error 1618: Line 116: Exponent '+1e' not ended with number. No file read.".

Is there any explanation for that?

I tried setprecision() to avoid outputing scientific notation 'e' in .lp file, CPLEX read but had poor efficiency work.

I appreciate your help.

> model20.lp
> MINIMIZE Z:
> +210x18331334XC+210y18331334YC+999999qb66
> -1e-005x01010102XB-1e-005x01020103XB-1e-005x01030104XB-1e-005x01040105XB-1e-005x01050106XB
> -1e-005x01060107XB-1e-005x01070108XB-1e-005x01080109XB-1e-005x01090110XB-1e-005x01100111XB
> -1e-005x01110112XB-1e-005x01120113XB-1e-005x01130114XB-1e-005x01140115XB-1e-005x01150116XB
> -1e-005x01160117XB-1e-005x01170118XB- ·············· -1e-005z20332034ZB-1e-005z20342035ZB

---

> model.lp
> MINIMIZE Z:
> +210x28332334XC+210y28332334YC+999999qb99 *(line116)*
> -1e-005x01010202XA-1e-005x01010302XA-1e-005x01010402XA-1e-005x01010502XA- ··············
> -2.94118e-007x28340135XD-2.94118e-007x29340135XD-2.94118e-007x30340135XD
> +1e-005x04020703XF+1e-005x04021703XF+1e-005x04022703XF+1e-005x04110712XF
> +1e-005x04111712XF+1e-005x04112712XF+1e-005x04220723XF+1e-005x04221723XF+··············

Comment: CPLEX is a commercial optimization library - is that right? Perhaps read their documentation on what formats can be in their input files

Comment: Thank you. The problem is CPLEX CAN read small model which has scientific notation 'e' , but NOT large model.

Comment: Just a small question - why are you generating an LP file to solve with CPLEX rather than create the model directly in CPLEX with one of the APIs?

Comment: @linlin - which is the small model, and which is the large one? If you want help, you'll need to provide more explicit details.

Comment: model20.lp is small one, model.lp is large one.